# FlashDevelop - spark components don't work

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flashdevelop, flex-spark

I am a beginner in Flex. I downloaded FlashDevelop, created a new Flex 4 application and added a simple snippet of code to test whether it worked. As I understand it, the app should print out 'hello'. Instead, it does nothing - just a blank window with no output to debug log whatsoever.

The weird thing is that if i substitute `<s:Application>` for `<mx:Application>`, it prints 'hello' just fine. But then it doesn't display any elements from the  namespace.

So I'm guessing this is a problem that has to do with Spark.

**Current setup:**

- FlashDevelop 4.4.2
- Compiling for SDK : Flex 4.6.0 and AIR 3.7 (I guess I'm not using AIR, though. And I even tried Flex 4.9.1, didn't work either)
- I'm not including any libraries other than the default in FD

**Main.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="trace('hello');">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: This code worked for me as is; and I Saw the trace in the Flash Builder Debug Console.  The problem must be either a configuration issue on your end or possibly related to how you compile and/or launch the app.  The fact that you see the trace for the MX Application, but not the Spark Applicaiton makes me think that things are properly configured; so i'm not sure where to point you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be the Flash Player version the project's being compiled for: [Why isn't this image showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636692/why-isnt-this-image-showing-up/17636904#17636904)